# Debugger Skipping Latest Checked-in Code in VS 2012 - Works with VS 2010

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, mstest

Edit: I just tried this with VS 2010, and the problem didn't occur. The issue only happens with VS 2012. Could this really be a bug? This is also happening on two separate laptops of mine, and even on a friend's laptop (that just got the latest code).

First, a screenshot of the problem. This method is all *new* code.

[image]

The debugger is skipping code from my recent check-in. The comments, in the code below, explain what is happening when I debug this method. So there really isn't a need to try and understand the code; just notice that lines of code are being skipped. If you're thinking that the code doesn't match the assembly being debugged, please bear with me. You'll see where the debugger recognizes new code, but not existing code. And this behavior is occurring on two different laptops, after deleting the code on disk and getting the latest again. Each comment tells you if the debugger hits a line.

```
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("PrestoCommon.dll")]
public void ApplicationShouldBeInstalledTest_UseCase9()
{
    // Debugger hits this line
    ApplicationServer appServerAccessor = new ApplicationServer();

    // Debugger does not hit these next two lines
    PrivateObject privateObject = new PrivateObject(appServerAccessor);
    ApplicationServer appServer = ApplicationServerLogic.GetByName("server10");

    // Debugger hits this line. Weirdness: both objects are null, and after this line runs,
    // appServerAccessor is no longer null.
    appServerAccessor.Id = appServer.Id;

    // Skips this line
    ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup appWithValidGroup = appServer.ApplicationsWithOverrideGroup[0];

    // Debugger hits this line, but F11 doesn't take me into the method.
    appWithValidGroup.CustomVariableGroup = CustomVariableGroupLogic.GetById("CustomVariableGroups/4");

    // Skips this line
    Assert.AreEqual(true, true);
}
```

The disassembly shows only the lines of code that actually get hit.

[image]

Now, check this out. If I add a new line of code, the debugger recognizes it, and the other lines of code change, as far as being recognized by the debugger. Just the second line of code, within the method, is new.

```
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("PrestoCommon.dll")]
public void ApplicationShouldBeInstalledTest_UseCase9()
{
    // Debugger hits this line
    ApplicationServer appServerAccessor = new ApplicationServer();

    // New line. It's recognized by the debugger, and it shows up in the disassembly.
    if (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)) { return; }

    // Debugger does not hit these next two lines
    PrivateObject privateObject = new PrivateObject(appServerAccessor);
    ApplicationServer appServer = ApplicationServerLogic.GetByName("server10");  // Gets hit now.

    // Debugger hits this line. Weirdness: both objects are null, and after this line runs,
    // appServerAccessor is no longer null.
    appServerAccessor.Id = appServer.Id;  // No longer gets hit.

    // Skips this line (now it's getting hit)
    ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup appWithValidGroup = appServer.ApplicationsWithOverrideGroup[0];

    // Debugger hits this line, but F11 doesn't take me into the method. Now this gets skipped.
    appWithValidGroup.CustomVariableGroup = CustomVariableGroupLogic.GetById("CustomVariableGroups/4");

    // Skips this line. Still skipped.
    Assert.AreEqual(true, true);
}
```

And here's a partial snapshot of the disassembly, showing the new line of code:

[image]

How can this be happening?

Adding to the weirdness, at one point this even returned:

```
if (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)) { return; }
```

Things I've tried:
- Delete source code from hard drive and force a get latest
- Repair VS 2012
- Do some VS [clean-up](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2011/11/08/clean-up-after-visual-studio.aspx)
- Use VS 2010, change code, check in, get latest with VS 2012
- Reboot
- Other (can't remember all of them)

Comment: can you perhaps show the `ForceInstallation` class ?

Comment: Rebuild your code. Also, look for the test runner process in Task Manager, and stop it. It may have an old version of your code.

Comment: I closed the solution, reopened, and rebuilt it. Same issue. There seem to be quite a few MsBuild processes running. I'm going to reboot and try again. I'll post the `ForceInstallation` class, even though I don't think that's it.

Comment: Maybe a debugger bug, probably not a bug in the binary. Try extracting the rest of the function (lines 2 and 3) into a separate function. This might hide the bug and prove the theory.

Comment: I just noticed that the debugger actually skips the first line of code. It's like I'm debugging a different version than what my code is showing. Rebooting...

Comment: I just rebooted, cleaned the solution, built the solution, and same problem. The debugger is skipping that line of code. Grrrr...

Comment: are you getting any warnings or anything when you are compiling..? what if you were to rebuild that application for example in a console application..do you get the same error.. also checkout the namespace at the project level and see if it matches the namespace in your .cs file where that code is that you are using.. I've seen something like this before .. and ForceInstallation, does that require a reference in the using section at top..

Comment: `this.ForceInstallationEnvironment.ToString()` in `ForceInstallation.ToString()` will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `_forceInstallationEnvironment` is `null`. And I wouldn't be surprised if debugger or something is calling it quietly.

Comment: @NikolayKhil I tried putting a breakpoint in `ToString()`, and I even tried returning `string.Empty` in `ToString()`. Neither worked. Thanks for the tip, though.

Comment: @DJ I am getting warnings. I can post them, but I don't see how they would cause this behavior. Rebuild in a console app? Do you man create a new console app and put the test code in it, and run it from there? `ForceInstallation` does require a using directive, and it's there.

Comment: yes.. did you make sure that the .pdb file was also deleted when you did the clean / rebuild..

Comment: I did. I even deleted the entire source code directory from my hard disk. I also added a new screenshot to my post. I simply don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I need to stop for the night. This is killing me. I updated the beginning of my post with new info. I may need to offer my first bounty. I don't get it...

Comment: I would be temped to delete the file with the bug and then try to run it and see what happens.

Comment: Are you on VS2012 Update1? Are you using debug builds with optimization turned OFF ?

Comment: Enable first chance exceptions and try again.

Comment: Is the project set up to build? Please check that, with the current Solution Configuration/Platform combination, the project's checkbox is filled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be unit-test specific. In VS 2012:

- Test > Test Settings
- Open the selected test settings file
- Data and Diagnostics > deselect Code Coverage (Visual Studio 2010)
- Apply

Note, I had the advantage of access to the source code, and I downloaded Presto (http://presto.codeplex.com/).

Comment: That worked! This also works by simply deselecting the file in Test -> Test Settings.